# How to replace an array containing number 3 with 4 in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
void replace3sWith4s(int[] replace){
  for (int i = 0;i<replace.length;i++){
      if (replace[i]==3);{
          replace[i]=4;
      }
  }
}
```

My program is replacing all numbers with #4 but I want to have an array that contains 3,
takes an integer array, and changes any element that has the value 3 to instead have the      value 4.

Comment: My suggestion is to use an Eclipse which supports checkstyle and automatic code formatting. If you were using them Eclipse would have highlighted that line as a warning. Of corurse it can't think for you but it can lead your hand in those silly cases.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (replace[i]==3);
                 ^^^
```

Remove the semicolon.
It should be

```
if (replace[i]==3) {
      replace[i]=4;
}
```

The semicolon changes the meaning to

```
if (replace[i]==3)
    ;//do nothing

// Separate New block
{
    replace[i]=4;
}
```

Comment: thanks im new to programming as you can tell always get caught on silly mistakes

Answer (score 3):

```
(replace[i]==3);
```

Is like writing

```
(replace[i]==3) { }
```

Which does nothing.

Your code is equivalent to this code:

```
void replace3sWith4s(int[] replace){
  for (int i = 0;i<replace.length;i++){
      if (replace[i]==3) { }
      replace[i]=4;  //Always reachable
      }
  }
}
```

To fix your code, remove the semicolon:

```
(replace[i]==3); 
               ^
```

Comment: +1, you really explained, instead just providing fix. And in short `condition turned in to statement`.

Answer (score -1):

also You can try this method at if statement according to your array type

```
if (replace[i].equals("3")){

replace[i]=4;
```

}

Comment: Y bro??
It's depend on types

Comment: `int` is a primitive, you cannot apply `equals` on it.

Comment: Ohh yes, Sry I didn't notice that int[]